# Can Paw display PDF as response instead of its raw value

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to have Paw (https://luckymarmot.com/paw) display the result of a request as PDF instead of the raw value (in case the repsonse is a PDF)? I am creating a lot of PDFs on the fly and this would be great for testing purposes.

It already offers a range of possibilities like text, json, xml or web...

Comment: Right, Paw cannot display PDF responses yet. We will be working on that for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No PDF display possible, they are working on it